# How to convert a SNAPSHOT build number into an integer with 3 digit using js

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with this issue forever now.
How can I write a js function to convert a version number (say 1.10.0-SNAPSHOT) into 1.1.0.For example: My current project build version is 1.10.0-SNAPSHOT. I want to be able to display 1.1.0 when the version is 1.10.0-SNAPSHOT and 1.2.0 for the next build version: 1.11.0-SNAPSHOT and 1.3.0 for the next build version: 1.12.0-SNAPSHOT  and so gets incremented whenever the build version increments.
Also I might have a scenario when the version falls below 10, i.e 3.9.0-SNAPSHOT, in that case i'm looking to do have 2.9.0 and when the version becomes 3.10.0-SNAPSHOT, it becomes 2.10.0.

```
2.13.0 //1.0.0
2.13.1 //1.0.1
2.14.0 //1.1.0
2.14.1//1.1.1
3.0.0 //2.0.0
3.0.1 //2.0.1
3.12.0 //2.12.0
3.12.1 //2.12.1
4.12.12 //3.12.12
8.2.0 //7.2.0
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The req chnage since I last posted..my apologies for that...I have tried this:   https://jsfiddle.net/madcobd4/    with Tanvi B code.But im stuck with version: 3.12.0/3.12.1/4.12.12..rest all work fine!

Comment: i figured out the way through it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question you wanted to convert 1.10-SNAPSHOT to this 1.1.0 
If you want to restrict it to only 3 decimal you can use below code

```
var stt ="1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-1";    
var mytext=stt.replace("-SNAPSHOT-","."); 
var t = mytext.split(".");
var m ="";
for(var j=0;j < 2;j++){

if(t[j]>9){  
    var sub = t[j].substring(0,1);     
    var sub2 = t[j].substring(2,1);      
    m= m+"."+sub+"."+sub2;
  }else{
    if(j==0){
      m = t[j];
    }else{
    m  = m+"."+t[j];
    }
  }
}//output 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below way

```
var stt ="1.10.0-SNAPSHOT-1";    
var mytext=stt.replace("-SNAPSHOT-","."); 
var t = mytext.split(".");
var m ="";
for(var j=0;j < t.length;j++){

if(t[j]>9){  
    var sub = t[j].substring(0,1);     
    var sub2 = t[j].substring(2,1);      
    m= m+"."+sub+"."+sub2;
  }else{
    if(j==0){
      m = t[j];
    }else{
    m  = m+"."+t[j];
    }
  }
}
```

m will be output //1.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks Tanvi B for the help..i tried here: https://jsfiddle.net/1d4qye8n/ it gives 1.1.0.0.1 also is there a way i can set 1.0.0 and not 1.0.0.1?Thx